# Is pasted HTML guaranteed to be sanitized?

Tags: html, security, contenteditable

I have a content editable div:

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

HTML can be pasted into that div. Is the HTML guaranteed not to have script tags or event handler attributes, etc.?

I have not found a source, but I am guessing that all browsers strip scripts. Otherwise, it seems very open to phishing-style user XSS: "see dancing ponies, by pasting this into Gmail..."

---

**Edit:** For example, Chrome strips the `<script>` element if you copy and paste with the following:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
Copy this:
<div>
  <b>Stack</b> <i>Overflow</i>
  <br>
  <script>
    if(document.querySelectorAll('div[contenteditable=true]').length) {
      alert('Hacked!');
    }
  </script>
  <img src="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png">
</div>
<br>
<br>
Into this: (if you see a `Hacked!` alert, the script was not stripped)
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Is this a guaranteed behavior? Or do I have to do something special to prevent XSS?

Comment: @AMostMajestuousCapybara, read the question. "Otherwise, it seems very open to phishing-style user XSS: 'see dancing ponies, by pasting this here...'" Chrome, FYI, does exactly this; it removes all scripts.

Comment: @AMostMajestuousCapybara, I don't understand. It certainly seems like HTML elements to me: http://jsfiddle.net/1npz523d/

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you're worried about here?

Comment: Self-XSS will always be a problem. "Hack into your friends' Facebook profile by hitting F12 and pasting this code in your console!" Personally I don't think it's your problem to worry about. What you *should* worry about is more traditional XSS.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, I'm not sure self XSS can be dismissed with a wave of the hand. If it can, why does opening the JS console on facebook.com (your example, not mine) say **STOP!**? Because they are foolishly worrying about something that is "not their problem"? Do I need to be worried about being hacked everytime I paste from a website into Gmail?

Comment: With the edits your question is actually understandable now. I think any reasonable browser would strip scripts yes, otherwise it would definitely be a security concern. I doubt it's specified anywhere however, the spec for `contenteditable` being quite light.

Comment: @AMostMajestuousCapybara, I think so too (and said as much). But I don't *know* so...hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, pasted HTML is **not** guaranteed to do not contain script tags and other forms of script embedding.

contenteditable is not a ready to use WYSIWYG editor but rather a mechanism to make editor on top of it. So don't expect pasted content filtering in it. That's responsibility of code on top of contenteditable to filter scripts, MS Word stuff, Apple richtext traces, etc.

Even more: HTML clipboard format is not specified anywhere. Each platform uses its own. E.g. Windows uses [CF_HTML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), OS X has its own that is not specified anywhere AFAIK, etc.